# Questions about memory warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have memory issues with my iOS app and I have several questions about that.

Firs of all, I'm working with iOS 6 and I'm using ARC.

Now let me explain my situation :

I have 2 views. From the first view, if I tap on a button, I create the second view (using `alloc` and `init`) and I display it as a modal using this code :

```
[self presentViewController:secondView animated:YES completion:^{
        [secondView prepareToDraw];   // Function I use to start my computations and rendering
}];
```

At some time, when computations are finished I want to close my second view and go back to the first view. I' using this code from my second view :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self finished];  // Function I use to free some malloc
}];
```

I run my application with Instruments Allocations and Leaks and I have no Leaks.

Here is the code of my `didReceiveMemoryWarning` :

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if ([self isViewLoaded] && ([[self view] window] == nil)) {
        self.view = nil;

        [self tearDownGL];

        if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == self.context) {
            [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
        }
        self.context = nil;
    }

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    NSLog(@"Resources freed");
}
```

The `tearDownGL` function frees OpenGLES resources like textures, vertex arrays, ...

When I run my application, after several switches between the first and second view I receive memory warnings and then my application crashes.

**Here are my questions :**

**1-** Is the application automatically freeing my UIImage, UIView, ... of my controllers? If not, how can I free them as I'm using ARC?
I also saw the `viewDidUnload` function but it's deprecated as the documentation says :

> Called when the controller’s view is released from memory. (Deprecated
>   in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and
>   so this method is never called.)

But if views are not purged anymore under low-memory conditions, how can I free more memory to prevent my application from crashing?
What should I do?

**2-** I put a breakpoint on the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` function for my 2 controllers. When I run the application on the simulator I simulate a memory warning.
I can see that the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called once for my 2 controllers.
But if I switch several times between my first and second controllers the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called once for my first view controller but is called several times for my second view controller. If I switched 3 times, the function will be called 3 times. So I guess, when I "close" my second view to go back to the first view, the second view is not freed and still exists. Why ? How can I force it to be destroyed ? (as I won't use it anymore and create a new one)
I create the second view controller in a function and I don't keep any reference to it (it is not stored in the class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should release (in ARC that means setting all strong references to nil) all memory (images, NSData objects, Arrays, all data represented by the model layer etc.) that are currently not required and can (easiyl) be re-created when they are used again. All of your other code should be written in a way that properties/iVars are checked for nil if those objects could have been released during a memory warning and then will be re-created.

I doubt that `self.view` is amongst that objects that might be disposal.

You may have displayed an UIImageView. That was probalby created with an UIImage object. You not not really need that UIImage in memory while the UIImageView is displayed. (If UIImageView still need it then it retains it or keeps a strong reference on its onw so that you don't have to worry about keeping the image itself.) THAT are the resources to be released.

If `self.context` is amongst the disposal resources, I cannot say. It may well be.

Comment: Setting variables to nil works for me. But it's weird, why isn't the variable freed at the end of the block directly?

Comment: With ARC it is freed when there is no strong reference left. There may be still weak references left. Weak references should be nil'ed automatically but do not rely on that. Without ARC the memory may be freed more or less by the end of the block only if it was autoreleased (and if there is no other not autoreleased retain on it).

Answer (score 1):

ARC does not always mean that the images, views ,etc gets released instantly. It gets added to the nearest arc pool and gets released.If the application may require it or uses it somewhere it gets added to the main pool which gets released only when the application terminates. So it is better to remove the object yourself if you think it has served it purpose. Especially in case of images it remains in the memory as it does not know whether it is getting used anywhere else or not.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you work with blocks, you should use a weak reference to self, since this can lead to retain cycles. So change your code to this:

```
__weak typeof(self) blockSelf = self;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [blockSelf finished];  // Function I use to free some malloc
}];
```

Also, your code to free anything should be in dealloc. You don't need a custom method for it, if it only happens at the end of the lifetime of that controller.

Your first call also seems wrong:

```
[self presentViewController:secondView animated:YES completion:^{
        [secondView prepareToDraw];   // Function I use to start my computations and rendering
}];
```

If `prepareToDraw` only happens once, when the controller is presented the first time, than you should run this code in `viewDidLoad`. This would also benefit your architecture, since only the controller itself should know what it has to setup in the beginning and to tearDown at the end.

Hope that helps. Perhaps you have other/more problems in your code.

Comment: I changed my code. it seems to work, however, hermann Klecker was the first one to answer and his answer solved my problem too so I accepted his answer

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at auto-relase pools : [AutoReleasePools](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)

It reads :

> Use Local Autorelease Pool Blocks to Reduce Peak Memory Footprint
>
> Many programs create temporary objects that are autoreleased. These objects add to the program’s memory footprint until the end of the block. In many situations, allowing temporary objects to accumulate until the end of the current event-loop iteration does not result in excessive overhead; in some situations, however, you may create a large number of temporary objects that add substantially to memory footprint and that you want to dispose of more quickly. In these latter cases, you can create your own autorelease pool block. At the end of the block, the temporary objects are released, which typically results in their deallocation thereby reducing the program’s memory footprint

I had a similar issue, where I encapsulated all the big objets that I wanted to get rid of in an `@autoreleasepool` block.

Comment: autoreleasepool seems to work. Your answer also solved my problem. However Hermann Klecker was the first one so  accepted his answer